# Failed to create ImageTargetObserver: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to use vuforia(10.15.4) in Hololens2.

This is working perfectly fine in Unity(2020.3.24)-Play mode. But after deploying to Hololens 2, it is failing. Outputlog get "Failed to create ImageTargetObserver: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR".